# Use indexOf() to find every match in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

If I have an array like `const fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "apple", "grape", "apple"]` how can I use `indexOf()` (or another function if one exists) to find the index of every match?

Put another way, `fruits.indexOf("apple")` will only return `0` right now, but I want way to return an array with every matching index: `[0, 3, 5]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#finding_all_the_occurrences_of_an_element) , Read the Docs

```
const indices = [];
const array = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "d"];
const element = "a";
let idx = array.indexOf(element);
while (idx !== -1) {
  indices.push(idx);
  idx = array.indexOf(element, idx + 1);
}
console.log(indices);
// [0, 2, 4]
```

Here, inside the while loop, the second argument of `indexOf` method  will determine the starting pointing point for finding index.

And the loop is updating it for next occurrences and storing it in an `indices` array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce()`:

```
const apples = fruits.reduce((result, fruit, index) => {
    if (fruit === "apple")
        result.push(index);
    return result;
}, []);
```

You could of course wrap that in a function so that you could pass an array and a value to look for, and return the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `Array#map` and `Array#filter` methods as follows:

```js
const 
      fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "apple", "grape", "apple"],
      
      matchFruit = fruit => fruits
          .map((f,i) => f === fruit ? i : -1)
          .filter(i => i > -1);
          
console.log( matchFruit( "apple" ) );
```